# ORDER BY clause not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

The SQL query below is ordering by the 'user' field ascending, but as you can see from the table below, it's not entirely working. The query definitely results in me getting the records in a different order, but it's clearly not sorted alphabetically. A similar result happens if I sort DESC instead. Lots of names beginning in 'T' sandwiched between a pair of names beginning in 'V' for instance.

[image]

```
4 Execute   select `laptops`.`id`, `laptops`.`asset_tag`, `laptops`.`serial`, `laptops`.`hostname`,
`locations`.`location`, `laptops`.`user`, `laptops`.`detected_user`, `laptops`.`recent_users`,
`models`.`model`, `models`.`vendor`, `types`.`type`, `statuses`.`status` from `laptops`
inner join `locations` on `locations`.`id` = `laptops`.`location_id`
left join `locations` as `detected_location` on `locations`.`id` = `laptops`.`detected_location_id`
inner join `models` on `models`.`id` = `laptops`.`model_id`
inner join `types` on `types`.`id` = `models`.`type`
left join `statuses` on `statuses`.`id` = `laptops`.`status`
where `laptops`.`scrapped` != 1
order by ISNULL(user), user asc 
limit 50 offset 0
```

Comment: Is it because user is reserved word?

Comment: What happens if you `ORDER BY laptops.user`?

Comment: Makes no difference.